# monitoring mongodb with monit

Tags: ubuntu, mongodb, monit

I cannot get the most basic script working on monitoring mongodb on ubuntu 16.04 monit 5.16

```
check process mongod with pidfile /var/run/mongod.pid
  group database
  start program = "/usr/sbin/service mongod start"
  stop program = "/usr/sbin/service mongod stop"
  if failed host 127.0.0.1 port 27017 protocol http
    and request "/" with timeout 15 seconds then restart
```

I get the error: `Error reading pid from file '/var/run/mongod.pid'`

but when I run `cat /var/run/mongod.pid` as a regular user I do get the value 51455

I've changed permissions making it both less (0x777) and more restrictive to no avail. Anyone come across this?

Answer (score 0):

Could try to change permission of mongodb pid file to **"mongodb process user":"monit process user"**, I think issue is mongodb normally running as mongodb user and monit as root, please try this.
Hope this will help.